# Jackson: json schema references other schemas, can this be disabled?

Tags: java, json, jsonschema, jackson-modules

When I use Jackson Json-Schema-Module, my schemas are generated using references that are pointed to each other.

Consider this schema:

This is a property object inside POJO1

```
    "myObject" : {
     "type" : "object",
     "id": "urn:jsonschema:package:myObject"
     "properties": {
          "property1" : {
             "type" : "string"
         },
          "property2" : {
             "type" : "string"
         }
    }
 }
```

I have the same property object inside POJO2, and when both schemas get generated, I get the following in POJO2:

```
  "myObject" : {
     "type" : "object",
     "$ref": "urn:jsonschema:package:myObject"
  }
```

But I want this property in POJO2'a schema be the same as in POJO1's schema, I don't want the reference. Can this be disabled? Or is there a workaround?

Here's the code I use:

```
for (Class clazz : classes) {

    ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper();
    SchemaFactoryWrapper visitor = new SchemaFactoryWrapper();
    m.acceptJsonFormatVisitor(m.constructType(clazz), visitor);
    JsonSchema jsonSchema = visitor.finalSchema();
    m.write(new File("json/" + clazz.getSimpleName() + ".json"), jsonSchema);

}
```

At first I thought that if use different ObjectMapper instances  for each schema construction I would get what I want, but not the case, apparently there's some sort of cache, my knowledge of such things is not deep enough to come to a right conclusion.

Thanks!

Comment: I've exactly the same query...

Comment: I've found an answer.

Comment: Tatu replied: Reply by Tatu Saloranta yesterday
Thank you for reporting that -- it is an unfortunate bug; while instances of VisitorContext were being created properly, part of the earlier fix had missed the fact that Map was still static.
So, 2.4.4 (and 2.5) will have the fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply override hashset and set it using java reflections like this:

```
Field f = visitorContext.getClass().getDeclaredField("seenSchemas");
      f.setAccessible(true);
      f.set(visitorContext, dummyHashSet);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can override VisitorContext

```
SchemaFactoryWrapper visitor = new SchemaFactoryWrapper();
visitor.setVisitorContext(new VisitorContext(){
        @Override
        public String addSeenSchemaUri(JavaType aSeenSchema) {
            return javaTypeToUrn(aSeenSchema);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a class VisitorContext which stores references, its methods are static, so I resolved this problem by changing the source code of this class.

Comment: It would be great if you could tell, how to use it, I've extended from that class but unable to use the new MyVisitorContext.

Comment: I had to download source code of the library, and make changes inside this class itself. I didn't find any other way. You can't override static methods.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can check this line:

```
m.acceptJsonFormatVisitor(m.constructType(clazz), visitor);
```

What kind of class is clazz? I am not sure, but instead clazz you can try something like:

```
myclass.class
```

Comment: I think it's fairly obvious that I am iterating through a list of classes.